# wordpress nginx config wont let me open pages using ?page_id=

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am trying to configure wordpress and came to the step when i want to use sample or my own pages. Unfortunately it seems like i didnt configure nginx correctly but i just cant seem to find howto. Either its an old or irrelevant to my version of nginx(1.2.1-2.2+wheezy2) or just incomplete. Can somebody provide a sample nginx wordpress config or just tell me which of the following is most correct to get it working?

```
    location /wordpress {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /etc/wordpress/index.php?$args;
    }
```

or

```
    location /wp/wp-content/ {
            alias /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }
```

or something else?

Comment: BTW, its even harder to understand how the secure nginx wordpress config would look like? should cgi.fix_pathinfo be false or not(for wordpress sake)? etc...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the nginx conf file I am using on my local mac for local development in case it helps:

```
user matt staff;
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  768;
}


http {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    include       mime.types;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    default_type  text/plain;
    server_tokens off;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    index index.html index.php;

    log_format  main  '[$time_local]: $domain - "$request" '
                  'status:$status bytes:$body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ';

    access_log  /Users/matt/Library/Logs/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log  /Users/matt/Library/Logs/nginx/error.log;

    upstream www-upstream-pool {
            server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name ~^(?:(?<subdomain>\w*)\.)?(?<domain>\w+)\.wp$;

        set $basepath "/Users/matt/pls-sites";

        set $rootpath "${domain}";

        if ($domain ~ 'wordpress'){
            set $rootpath "wordpress/httpdocs/web";
        }
        root $basepath/$rootpath;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;


        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # /index.html;
        }
        error_page  404              /404.html;

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location ~ .php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass www-upstream-pool;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer Matt, but i still dont understand how the page_id lookup works in wordpress. Is it index.php which resolves eg ?page_id=2? and maps it to something somewhere? In this case i understand the try_files directive